# 2 columns li inside ul, wont fill 100% of the ul width

Tags: html, css

I can't get UL's li elements to fill 100% of the width (or near).

Something strange happens, because the first one is next to parent's boreder, but the second column, has like a 20 px offset from the right parent's border.

[image]

```
.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul {
    border: solid 1px;
}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

It is affected by Bootstrap 3

Also I have to use 49% because 50% wont make 2 columns

```
Live page is under development in [www.hugotrinchero.com.ar][2]
```

Comment: please post your HTML and CSS so we can help you.

Comment: @DanO it is a wordpress plugin I am trying to customize.

Comment: You have to use `calc` in css. the calculation would be `width:calc( (100%/2)-margin )`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're dealing with `inline-block` elements, you need to set `font-size` to `0` for the parent element, in order to remove whitespace gaps.
 (Reset than `font-size` for the children elements).

**Now, three ways to do it:**

### Solution 1 `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul {
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  font-size:0;
}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul li {
  font-size: 16px; /* or use 1rem; for Root em */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  box-sizing: border-box;  /* Will eliminate the border wrap issue */
  width: 50%;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest-posts">
  <div class="latest-posts-widget">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda culpa numquam earum error provident et. A quibusdam laboriosam voluptates quae sunt ducimus amet nisi, commodi, corporis totam distinctio recusandae, porro.</li>
      <li>Beatae nulla iure enim illo assumenda doloribus quasi sit delectus molestias ut nam aut corrupti ea laborum unde consectetur rem maxime velit esse a quis sunt, asperiores veniam. Qui, sunt?</li>
      <li>Amet eius vitae ratione numquam, recusandae at sunt, quia eaque temporibus non excepturi sed perferendis perspiciatis, ducimus est, quasi harum? Laboriosam consequatur harum eius, repellat quaerat ratione natus quos commodi.</li>
      <li>Delectus cumque repellat, tempore in vitae, libero illum? Maiores itaque, facilis quas hic, aliquam modi corporis atque pariatur repellat enim! Qui dignissimos quia perferendis rerum, at quis mollitia aut quos.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution 2 `calc(50% - 2px)`

Using `calc()` and `font-size:0;` to remove *whitespace* gaps.
In `50% - 2px` the 2px accounts for the 1px + 1px borders:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul {
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  font-size:0;
}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: 1rem; /* Root-EM to fight parent's 0 */
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  border: #000 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest-posts">
  <div class="latest-posts-widget">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda culpa numquam earum error provident et. A quibusdam laboriosam voluptates quae sunt ducimus amet nisi, commodi, corporis totam distinctio recusandae, porro.</li>
      <li>Beatae nulla iure enim illo assumenda doloribus quasi sit delectus molestias ut nam aut corrupti ea laborum unde consectetur rem maxime velit esse a quis sunt, asperiores veniam. Qui, sunt?</li>
      <li>Amet eius vitae ratione numquam, recusandae at sunt, quia eaque temporibus non excepturi sed perferendis perspiciatis, ducimus est, quasi harum? Laboriosam consequatur harum eius, repellat quaerat ratione natus quos commodi.</li>
      <li>Delectus cumque repellat, tempore in vitae, libero illum? Maiores itaque, facilis quas hic, aliquam modi corporis atque pariatur repellat enim! Qui dignissimos quia perferendis rerum, at quis mollitia aut quos.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution 3 `box-shadow: inset`

Simply use `50%` and instead of the problematic border use `box-shadow`:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul {
  border:    solid 1px;
  font-size:  0;
}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul li {
  font-size:  16px;
  display:    inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:      50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest-posts">
  <div class="latest-posts-widget">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda culpa numquam earum error provident et. A quibusdam laboriosam voluptates quae sunt ducimus amet nisi, commodi, corporis totam distinctio recusandae, porro.</li>
      <li>Beatae nulla iure enim illo assumenda doloribus quasi sit delectus molestias ut nam aut corrupti ea laborum unde consectetur rem maxime velit esse a quis sunt, asperiores veniam. Qui, sunt?</li>
      <li>Amet eius vitae ratione numquam, recusandae at sunt, quia eaque temporibus non excepturi sed perferendis perspiciatis, ducimus est, quasi harum? Laboriosam consequatur harum eius, repellat quaerat ratione natus quos commodi.</li>
      <li>Delectus cumque repellat, tempore in vitae, libero illum? Maiores itaque, facilis quas hic, aliquam modi corporis atque pariatur repellat enim! Qui dignissimos quia perferendis rerum, at quis mollitia aut quos.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Addition to solution 1: optionally clear the floats after each line with `.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul li:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: both; }`

Comment: Hey thanks, the solution was very simple, I remembered that when dealing with inline-block elements, the whitespaces were a pain in the ass and one trick was using font-size: 0 in the container and restore it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 49%;
```

This means 98% of total width, thus there's a margin on the right. Since you're using a fixed-width layout, I suggest you use a fixed width for the `li` element, too.

On my machine (Google Chrome, Windows 8.1) I see one column, not two. That's because code like yours will cause unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Yes that was because I was testing. I fixed it by setting font-size 0 on the UL and font-size: 12 in the ul > li

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was with `white spaces` and the `display: inline-block`.

I added `font-size: 0` to the container ul and restored it in the `ul > li: font-size: 12px;`

```
.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

.latest-posts .latest-posts-widget ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now the columns are 50% 50%.

The border isn't affecting the layout since it is using `border-box`

[image]